# optimization sql query update depend of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I did a sql query for specific need, but I am not a professional of SQL, so i need help to "improve" the query.

Firstly, I have 3 tables :

- user (id, username, ...)
- action (id, point, limitPerDay)
- history (id, user_id, action_id, created_at, is_used_for_score)

Each time user do a specific action, it is log in history table (is_used_for_score will be true or false if limit has been reached or not)

But I need query for update all is_used_for_score because under certain conditions is_used_for_score can be pass from false to true

My query actually is

```
SET @num := 0, @user_id := 0, @type := '', @date := '';

UPDATE history SET is_used_for_score = 1 WHERE history.id IN (
    SELECT history_id FROM (
        SELECT 
            history.id AS history_id,
            action.limitPerDay AS limit_per_day,
            action.point,   
            @num := IF(
                @type = action_id, 
                IF(
                    @date = CONCAT(YEAR(history.created_at), '-', MONTH(history.created_at), '-', DAY(history.created_at)), 
                    IF (
                        @user_id = user_id,
                        @num + 1,
                        1
                    ), 
                    1
                ), 
                1
            ) AS row_number,
            @user_id := user_id AS user_id,
            @type := action_id AS action_id,
            @date := CONCAT(YEAR(history.created_at), '-', MONTH(history.created_at), '-', DAY(history.created_at)) AS `date`
        FROM history
        LEFT JOIN `action` ON action.id = action_id
        HAVING (row_number <= limit_per_day) OR (limit_per_day IS NULL)
        ORDER BY history.created_at ASC, user_id, action_id
    ) AS history_id_count_for_vote
);
```

But, I am pretty sure is probably not the best way to do that. Did you have some suggestion which can improve the query ?

Thank you

Comment: There's no way I'm wading through that. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Describe, in English, how `is_used_for_score` needs to be computed.

Answer (score 1):

On the issues like this, I'm repeating relentlessly, again and again: SQL is a DECLARATIVE language, do NOT forget this (slipping into imperativeness, just like you do)!

That means, that you're going to define, DECLARE the set(s) you going to work with - in other words, tell the Engine WHAT you want, leaving HOWs at its discretion.

That's the cornerstone.

So try to think through it like this: "I need to update SOME set of records [ones fell under '... certain conditions is_used_for_score can be pass from false to true'], so let's define that set first"

And that is what you lacking here - so please go ahead, define these conditions  and update your question with it, cause it's quite a time-eater trying to extract it from that mess you've posted.

Comment: Relentlessly, again and again? You've answered 14 questions. But agree on last point!

Comment: stackoverflow is not the only place on that planet :-)

Comment: Oh but it is! :-)